# [ros2run]: Process exited with failure 1

Tags: python, ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I try to write a simple programm with ros2.

when i run `ros2 run test_ur_controller first_moveit_node`  i get following output.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/.../workspace/moveit_test/install/test_ur_controller/lib/test_ur_controller/first_moveit_node", line 33, in <module>
sys.exit(load_entry_point('test-ur-controller==0.0.0', 'console_scripts', 'first_moveit_node')()) 
File "/home/.../workspace/moveit_test/install/test_ur_controller/lib/python3.10/site-packages/test_ur_controller/first_moveit_node.py", line 13, in main
node = test_moveit_node()
File "/home/.../workspace/moveit_test/install/test_ur_controller/lib/python3.10/site-packages/test_ur_controller/first_moveit_node.py", line 8, in __init__
super().__init__("first_moveit_node")
TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)
[ros2run]: Process exited with failure 1
```

My file `first_moveit_node.py` looks like this

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node

class test_moveit_node():

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("first_moveit_node")
        self.get_logger().info("Hello moveit")

def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args) 
    node = test_moveit_node()
    rclpy.spin(node) 
    rclpy.shutdown()
```

In my `setup.py` file i added:

```
entry_points={
    'console_scripts': [
        "first_moveit_node = test_ur_controller.first_moveit_node:main"
    ],
},
```

I already build my workspace `colcon build` which was successful.
Furthermore i `source ~/workspace/moveit_test/install/setup.bash` afterwards.

Where is my mistake?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/407533/%5Bros2run%5D:-process-exited-with-failure-1/) by [LucB](https://answers.ros.org/users/119094/lucb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 42 on 2022-10-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The class must inherits from (or is a subclass of) `Node`. You are missing it! Please see a complete working example below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node


class TestMoveitNode(Node):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("first_moveit_node")
        self.get_logger().info("Hello moveit")


def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)
    node = TestMoveitNode()
    rclpy.spin(node)
    rclpy.shutdown()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This is how I run it:

```
$ ros2 run  examples_rclpy_minimal_publisher first_moveit_node 
[INFO] [1665138307.033597919] [first_moveit_node]: Hello moveit
```

---

Please feel free to look at [the documentation](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Tutorials/Beginner-Client-Libraries/Writing-A-Simple-Py-Publisher-And-Subscriber.html).

---

Originally posted by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) with karma: 1744 on 2022-10-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [LucB](https://answers.ros.org/users/119094/lucb/) on 2022-10-07**:
Thanks. This worked.

At the Documentation for [Moveit2](https://moveit.picknik.ai/humble/doc/examples/move_group_interface/move_group_interface_tutorial.html) i can only find a code example for C++. All the examples with the python interface are for ros1. Could you suggest me any tutorial with a python example?

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2022-10-07**:
I am glad you made it work. By the way, when you are getting started with ROS 2, I recommend going through ROS 2 tutorials instead of MoveIt tutorials. Therefore, please feel free to look at the ROS2 documentation titled ["Writing a simple publisher and subscriber (Python)"](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Tutorials/Beginner-Client-Libraries/Writing-A-Simple-Py-Publisher-And-Subscriber.html).